# Is there an option to limit the number of visible data for chartkick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartkick

I'm making a simple realtime lineChart but I want to show a specific maximum amount of data, becaue the data will be added continuously and that might make it look messy when there is too much data.

```
<LineChart id="line1" data={fetchData2} colors={["#3F88C5"]} refresh={1} library={library}  messages={{empty: "No data"}} download={true}/>
```

For example I want to show only the last 20 inserted data.

Comment: You can write in  your model to limited this

Comment: as Lucas Henrique said you can for example return only the last 10 data from fetchData2 and pass it to data props

Comment: I thought about that, but I was hoping if it would be as a chartkick option.. like the min and max for values